# How to remove the admin privilege of a second Trello account

Tags: trello

I have two Trello accounts but don't want to use one. How do I remove the admin privilege of the one account I don't want to use?  When I enter text in a card and sign my name, it identifies the “wrong” or unwanted user ID—the one I want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You are logged into the "wrong" account.

Open the board you wish to remove this account from and remove yourself.
If you created an Organization, remove that name form the Org.

Log OUT of all accounts, then back in with the account you want to keep.